# How to setMinDate() using String date formate?

Tags: android

`String date = 10/11/2020;`

How do I use this date to setMinDate using Date picker dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());   
long l = simpleDateFormat.parse("10/11/2020").getTime();
```

and use that l to set min date